# Setting up PG's HStore and Preferences with Rails 4.1 and Spree 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree, pg, hstore

Currently, I am implementing an hstore column into a Rails app and I'm getting:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near ':' at position 4
: UPDATE "spree_line_items" SET "preferences" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "spree_line_items"."id" = 1
from /Users/benmorgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `get_last_result'
```

I ran a this migration to enable HStore:

```
class EnableHashStore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    enable_extension :hstore
  end

  def down
    disable_extension :hstore
  end
end
```

Then I ran a migration to add the `hstore` column:

```
class AddPreferencesToLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :spree_line_items, :preferences, :hstore
  end

  def down
    remove_column :spree_line_items, :preferences
  end
end
```

Once that was finished, I added a preference to the spree line items as well as a `store_accessor`:

```
Spree::LineItem.class_eval do
  preference :event_username, :string
end
```

I then tested out this new functionality by hitting up the console. Here's one example session:

```
[1] pry(main)> line_item = Spree::LineItem.first
=> #<Spree::LineItem id: 1, variant_id: 9, order_id: 1, quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff428dda6e8,'0.1599E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2014-09-06 07:25:19", updated_at: "2014-09-06 07:25:20", currency: "USD", cost_price: #<BigDecimal:7ff428dd9bf8,'0.17E2',9(18)>, tax_category_id: 2, adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428dd9ab8,'0.8E0',9(18)>, additional_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428dd99f0,'0.8E0',9(18)>, promo_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428dd9928,'0.0',9(18)>, included_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428dd9860,'0.0',9(18)>, pre_tax_amount: nil, preferences: {:event_username=>nil}>
[2] pry(main)> Spree::LineItem
=> Spree::LineItem(id: integer, variant_id: integer, order_id: integer, quantity: integer, price: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, currency: string, cost_price: decimal, tax_category_id: integer, adjustment_total: decimal, additional_tax_total: decimal, promo_total: decimal, included_tax_total: decimal, pre_tax_amount: decimal, preferences: hstore)
[3] pry(main)> line_item.preferences
=> {:event_username=>nil}
[4] pry(main)> line_item.set_preference(:event_username, "BenMorganIO")
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> line_item.preferences
=> {:event_username=>"BenMorganIO"}
[6] pry(main)> line_item.save
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near ':' at position 4
: UPDATE "spree_line_items" SET "preferences" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "spree_line_items"."id" = 1
from /Users/benmorgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `get_last_result'
```

Also, using the `store_accessor` on the `preferences` for the `event_username` doesn't help:

```
Spree::LineItem.class_eval do
  store :preferences, accessors: [:event_username], coder: JSON

  preference :event_username, :string
end
```

A session gives me:

```
[1] pry(main)> line_item = Spree::LineItem.first
=> #<Spree::LineItem id: 1, variant_id: 9, order_id: 1, quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:7ff428c06ba0,'0.1599E2',18(18)>, created_at: "2014-09-06 07:25:19", updated_at: "2014-09-06 07:25:20", currency: "USD", cost_price: #<BigDecimal:7ff428c060b0,'0.17E2',9(18)>, tax_category_id: 2, adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428c05f70,'0.8E0',9(18)>, additional_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428c05ea8,'0.8E0',9(18)>, promo_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428c05de0,'0.0',9(18)>, included_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7ff428c05d18,'0.0',9(18)>, pre_tax_amount: nil, preferences: {:event_username=>nil}>
[2] pry(main)> line_item.set_preference :event_username, "BenMorganIO"
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> line_item.save
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Unexpected end of string
: UPDATE "spree_line_items" SET "preferences" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "spree_line_items"."id" = 1
from /Users/benmorgan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `get_last_result'
```

Does anyone know how to save preferences in Spree 2.3/Rails 4.1?

Comment: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5460